# Pyomo 5.1.1 Solvers

Tags: pyomo, clp

anyone knows if I can use the solver CLP in my problem modeled in PyOMO? I found only informations about the old version of pyomo where this was not possible. I'd like to know if it still impossible to use them together. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Some examples of what you have tried would be ideal

Comment: thanks, i was just trying to use CLP as my solver but Im not sure it's compatible with PyOmo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pyomo is able to use the CBC solver through the AMPL solver library interface. The default linear solver in CBC is CLP. You could go that route.

Upshot: if you call the CBC solver from Pyomo with a linear model, it should be solved using CLP.